# Type 'UseFormRegister<AppointmentProps>' is not assignable to type 'UseFormRegister<FieldValues>

Tags: typescript, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I'm trying to learn TypeScript and react-hook-form, and I get this warning. What I'm doing is passing the `register` as a prop,

```
Type 'UseFormRegister<AppointmentProps>' is not assignable to type 'UseFormRegister<FieldValues>
enter code here
```

This is my Appointment.tsx

```
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
    <div className="flex flex-col gap-4">
      <AppointmentForm
        type="text"
        placeholder="Full Name"
        error={errors.fullName}
        name="fullName"
        register={register}
      />
     </div>
   </form>
```

This is AppointmentForm.tsx

```
export default function AppointmentForm({
  type,
  placeholder,
  error,
  name,
  register
}: AppointmentFormProps) {
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col gap-2">
      <Label>{placeholder}</Label>
      <Input placeholder={placeholder} type={type} {...register(name)}  />
      {error && (
        <span className="text-sm text-red-600 error-message">
          {error.message}
        </span>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

types.ts

```
export interface AppointmentFormProps {
    type: string;
    placeholder: string;
    error: FieldError | undefined;
    name: string;
    register: UseFormRegister<FieldValues>;
  }

export type AppointmentProps =  {
    fullName: string;
   
}
```

Comment: Are you using react-hook-form package?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the     
`"react-hook-form": "^7.50.1",`
 @LinDu

Comment: Can you provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example?